# how to upload the file in react-native for android

Tags: react-native

I tried for the uploading the image using react-native-file-transfer-android.
  But it not uploading, It gives response  like this

> object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   **Here is my code:**

```
var FileTransfer = require('react-native-file-transfer-android');
selectPhotoTapped() {
    const options = {
      quality: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true
      }
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };
        FileTransfer.upload({
          uri: source.uri,
          uploadUrl: 'http://52.34.32.119/FileUploadHandler.ashx?upload=start',
          fileName: 'temp.jpg',
          mimeType: 'image/jpg',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          data: {

          }
        }, (err, res) => {
          if(err) {
            alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(err))
            console.error(err);
          } else {
            alert("res:"+JSON.stringify(res))
            console.log(res);
          }
        });
this.setState({
          avatarSource: source
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Can any one give me some suggestions that is there any wrong in my code. Or give me suggestions that how to upload the file. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in an 'options' object into a your showImagePicker() call but this doesn't appear to be defined?

Comment: @issac Osiemo thanks for the reply here my questions is that, how to upload the file to server in android, i used modules like react-native fileupload

Comment: Since you are using node js consider using a package like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to do the post request to you're remote api. I have a sample here you can look at https://zacck.github.io/node/2017/03/28/Send-Promises-for-Weather.html